# How to make mouse navigation?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I am using LibGDX for my game and I want the mouse to move the "head" of the player, eg. like in Minecraft. How would I achieve this? I have got it to kinda work with yaw and pitch values that glRotateF what is being rendered, but the mouse moves outside the window (obviously) after a while of turning right. I have tried to use the robot class to reset the pointer position to the center of the screen but then navigation is nearly impossible.

Here is my player class:

```
package com.amzoft.gdxracingtestgamething;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL11;

public class Player implements InputProcessor{

    int pitch = 0;
    int yaw = 0;

    public Player()
    {

    }

    public void render()
    {
        GL11 gl = Gdx.gl11;
        gl.glRotatef(-yaw, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(-pitch, 1, 0, 0);
    }

    /*....a ton of unused implemented methods*/

    int xBefore = 0;
    int yBefore = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean touchMoved(int x, int y) 
    {
        if(xBefore<x-3)
        {
            yaw += 1;
        }
        if(xBefore>x+3)
        {
            yaw -= 1;
        }
        if(yBefore<y-3)
        {
            pitch -= 1;
        }
        if(yBefore>y+3)
        {
            pitch += 1;
        }
        if(yaw > 90)yaw = 90;
        if(yaw < -90)yaw = -90;
        if(pitch > 90)pitch = 90;
        if(pitch < -90)pitch = -90;
        xBefore = x;
        yBefore = y;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) 
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Im sorry if the solution is very obvious, I am very new to 3D game development and LibGDX.

Comment: anyone know how to accomplish this?? I know it probably involves trigonometry which I dont understand (yet)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigonometry :)
I used gluLookAt to make the camera look at the coordinates that were calculated from the sine, cosine and negative cosine of the yaw and pitch. It works pretty well.